# Is there a way to add AdMob to a Trusted Web Activity?

Tags: google-play, admob, android-manifest, trusted-web-activity, twa

I am currently using [GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) as a base for my project.

Is there a way to add AdMob interstitials or banner ads within the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add AdMob to an App that uses Trusted Web Activity, but the ads can only be displayed in native activities - they can't be added to the Trusted Web Activity itself.

Web based ads libraries (eg: Google Adsense) will work as expected inside a Trusted Web Activty.